# Dealing with 2D array element indexes in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 2D boolean array and I’m trying to set the elements surrounded by true to the value “true”:

For example:

```
[[T,T,T,F],[T,F,T,T],[T,T,T,T]]
```

Would become:

```
[[T,T,T,F],[T,T,T,T],[T,T,T,T]]
```

The `false` in the second raw and the second column would be `true`.

So I think I'm gonna need the index for every element to compare this seems easy in other languages like java but I need to do it in python.

I tried to do this in a for loop as :

```
For i in Range(len(s)) :
    If s[i+1] 
    If s[i-1]
```

And of course, tried it with two for loops. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post your full code so the problem is reproducible. Then explain what is going wrong with the code. Then people can help you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it just like you would in Java or any other language. Here's one possible implementation that doesn't use numpy and might be more beginner-friendly. You didn't specify if it includes the corners, so this only factors in the ones that are directly adjacent.

```
for row_index in range(len(s)):                 # Loops through each row in the array
    for col_index in range(len(s[row_index])):  # Loops through each column in the row
        # Make sure you check for out of bounds
        if ((row_index > 0 and s[row_index - 1][col_index]) and
            (row_index < len(s)-1 and s[row_index + 1][col_index]) and
            (col_index > 0 and s[row_index][col_index - 1]) and
            (col_index < len(s[0])-1 and s[row_index][col_index + 1])):
            s[row_index][col_index] = True
```

Comment: I haven't looked to see what your answer does, but the question shows a False value in the corner which remains False despite being adjacent only to True values, so the implication is that only elements in the interior of the array can be changed.

Comment: Good catch, I'll fix that

Comment: Separately, I took it to be that "surrounded by" includes those that are diagonally adjacent (all 8 surrounding elements must be True for an element to become True), but there is enough ambiguity in the question that it could just refer to the 4 that are adjacent in the orthogonal directions.

Comment: Upon looking again, it seems that I only change elements on the interior of the array as a side-effect of the way I checked the boundaries. In other words, I wrote it wrong initially, but it ended up doing what it should have by accident

Comment: Well it certainly works. And although it mightn't be particularly fast, it will work with a list of lists equally well as with a 2d numpy array.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

T = True
F = False

a = np.array([[T,T,T,F],[T,F,T,T],[T,T,T,T]])

a[1:-1, 1:-1] |= (a[:-2,  :-2] & a[:-2, 1:-1] & a[:-2,  2:] &
                  a[1:-1, :-2]                & a[1:-1, 2:] &
                  a[2:,   :-2] & a[2:,  1:-1] & a[2:,   2:])

print(a)
```

gives:

```
[[ True  True  True False]
 [ True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True]]
```

Or if by "surrounded by" you just mean the four elements that are directly adjacent (not diagonally adjacent), then the expression becomes:

```
a[1:-1, 1:-1] |= (               a[ :-2, 1:-1]               &              
                  a[1:-1, :-2]                 & a[1:-1, 2:] &
                                 a[2:,   1:-1]              )
```

maybe better written as:

```
a[1:-1, 1:-1] |= (a[:-2, 1:-1] & a[1:-1, :-2] & a[1:-1, 2:] & a[2:, 1:-1])
```

And the result for this particular example array is the same as before.